# JSoup .textNodes() count

Tags: jsoup

```
Document doc1 = Jsoup.parse("<a>foo&nbsp;  \r\n   <!--comment-->\r\n</a>");
        List<TextNode> textNodes1 = (doc1.getElementsByTag("a").get(0)).textNodes();
        System.out.print(String.valueOf(textNodes1.size()));
```

With last  \r\n added to parsed doc, textNodes1.size() becomes 2  !?

I only see one text node.

Final Aim here is to replace all \r\n in between a tags & trim.

Comment: What is the problem? Of course the `\r\n`after the comment will result in a TextNode while parsing, since the text of the `a` element is divided by the comment. can you clarify your problem with this?

Comment: I guess I would expect comment is not a tag, hence you can't have a 2 text nodes there. Comment should be ignored when parsing.  As said, trying to clear linefeed & trim because browser interprets any number of linefeeds & spaces as single space. And those are there only because of code format and not as someting that should be displayed.

Comment: Why don't you clean the html before parsing?

Comment: Finaly I did that, remove comments befor parsing and now it is managable.But that is beyond the point. Point is to solve minor but annoying bad display of html.